# Write to file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a textarea and a save button..I want to capture the data in the textarea and write it to a file but am getting problems..Am getting problems in writing the code for ajax.Note i am not using form.

```
    <textarea  id="display" name="display" style="overflow:auto;resize:none"     rows="35" cols="40"><?php echo $data;?></textarea>



       <input type="button" name="Save" value="Save" onclick="save_data()"/>

    This is the Ajax i wrote...
    function save_data(){

            var ajaxadd;
            ajaxadd=new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "save.php";
            ajaxadd.open("GET",url,true);
            ajaxadd.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajaxadd.readyState==4){
                    document.getElementById('display').value = ajaxadd.responseText;
                }
            }
            ajaxadd.send(null);
            alert("Item successfully ADDED!");
        }


    This is the save.php
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
        $data = $_POST['data'];
        $fname ="XHTML_file.xhtml";

        $file = fopen($fname, 'w');//creates new file
        fwrite($file, $data);
        fclose($file);
    }
?>
```

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting exceptions...nor any error..its just that the contents from the textarea is not being written to the file

Comment: So you are modifying file at client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the get method and not sending any data.
Use post, and send the data:

```
function save_data(){
    var ajaxadd;
    ajaxadd=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "save.php";
    ajaxadd.open("POST",url,true);
    ajaxadd.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxadd.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById('display').value = ajaxadd.responseText;
        }
    }

    var textArea = document.getElementById('display');
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("data", textArea.value); 

    ajaxadd.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: how can i call the function above when clicking on a button

Comment: I just changed the content of your save_data function, i shall add the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a GET request:

```
ajaxadd.open("GET",url,true);
```

But you are expecting a POST request:

```
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
```

and you aren't sending any data:

```
ajaxadd.send(null);
```

Comment: can you please help me,am badly stuck

Answer (score 0):

First you are doing a get request and you are testing the post-variable at the server. Second: you never added the data from the text area to the request. You have to do that manually since you are not submitting a form